# UIView Swipe Gesture Changing images

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to implement a left and right swipe gesture to change the image on my UIView.

I have done the following:

```
if art_title.text == "Art Collection" {
        var imageList = ["Boulder Bean","Mother of Earth","Bamboozled","Black Figures","Modest Angel"]
        var index = 0

        func leftSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

            if index < imageList.count - 1 {
                index = index + 1
                art_image.image = UIImage(named: imageList[index])
            }
        }

        func rightSwipe(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            if index > 0 {
                index = index - 1
                art_image.image = UIImage(named: imageList[index])
            }
        }
    }
```

I am now getting a crash when i try to swipe on Any annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you will have a List of images and an Index value to track where you are in the list.

When you "swipe right" you decrement the index by 1... when you swipe left, you increment the index by 1.

If the index drops below 0 (the first element of your array), you either reset it to 0 and leave the image as-is, or you "wrap it around" to the end of the array. Similarly, if the index gets greater than the number of elements in the array, you can "wrap it around" to zero.

So, for example:

```
// initialize
var imageList = ["flower", "balloon", "cat", "dog"]
var index = 0

// set the first image
art_image.image = UIImage(named: imageList[index])

// on swipe left (arrays are Zero based)
if index < imageList.count - 1 {
    index = index + 1
    art_image.image = UIImage(named: imageList[index])
}

// on swipe right
if index > 0 {
    index = index - 1
    art_image.image = UIImage(named: imageList[index])
}
```

and so on...

That should get you on your way.

Comment: I can't do an Image list as this app is a MapView app and this is for a specific Annotation. This is the only Annotation that has multiple images and I currently have it select the correct image based on the Annotation that is clicked on.

Comment: No real difference... If you get to this Annotation - that has multiple images - instead of a hard-coded list of image names, get references to each image an put them in a list. You may need to reference them in a different manner than UIImage(named:), but the process is the same.

Comment: I have added code above of How I've tried to implement it but I am producing several errors.

Comment: Hmmm... well, some of this is fundamentals, so not sure how much help this will be if you don't already know it, but...  I edited your pastebin code here: http://pastebin.com/ufxjSmXd  I can't test it, because I don't have the rest of your app that's displaying the maps / pins / etc, but this is the *general* idea.

Comment: I have altered it to `if art_title.text == "Art Collection"` Which causes no errors, however, when I try a swipe on any Annotation it crashes the app. I've updated my code file.

Comment: Ah ok yeah I was putting the if loop outside of the @IBAction. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Outstanding good job